# EntityFramework.Extended Audit - foreign key property IsRelationship always false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, audit-logging, entityframework.extended

I am using the EntityFramework.Extended library to implement audit logging in my system. However, when I update the foreign key 'TitleId' on my Person object, it does not register it as a foreign key and does not replace the Id with my chosen display field.

**Audit log config:** (this is called in my Global.asax startup file)

```
public static class AuditLogConfiguration
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var auditConfiguration = AuditConfiguration.Default;

            auditConfiguration.IncludeRelationships = true;
            auditConfiguration.LoadRelationships = true;
            auditConfiguration.DefaultAuditable = true;

            // Use abbreviation value in audit log whenever Title is used as foreign key
            auditConfiguration.IsAuditable<Title>()
                .DisplayMember(x => x.Abbreviation);
        }
    }
```

**Person entity:**

```
public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Title")]
        public int TitleId { get; set; }

        public string Forename { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Title entity:**

```
public class Title
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Update logic:**

```
var audit = BeginAudit();

person.TitleId = model.TitleId;

SaveChanges();

var log = audit.LastLog;
```

When lookign through the property changes in `audit.LastLog`, the TitleId modification is not recognized as a relationship and is not applying my display conversion specified in the config.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute for foreign key should go on the navigation property, not the foreign key itself:

```
[ForeignKey("TitleId")]
public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
```

But in this case you don't need the attribute at all, because your class is following a naming convention that Entity Framework recognises

And, since `Title` isn't the foreign key - `TitleId` is, I'd try this:

```
// Use abbreviation value in audit log whenever TitleId is used as foreign key
auditConfiguration.IsAuditable<TitleId>()
                  .DisplayMember(x => x.Abbreviation);
```

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, I have tried all methods of explicitly declaring a foreign key and the issue still occurs.